# How to Export Data set from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying export a dataSet from Azure Data factory. I have created the dataset by pulling Salesforce account data and now I'm trying to look at it in Excel to make sure the data looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome ,
if you ask me all the ETL tools does two things for sure , they import data from source and export to sink , just kiding

In your case you can use a copy activity and for the  source part your are  already set , for sink add a storage account and select the format as excel .

Comment: I guess excel as output is not yet supported in ADF. I don't see a way to select it in sink, unless you use Binary dataset. But then, your source needs to be binary dataset as well.